# can't get the POST parameters in django

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to make a login-page using django, I am facing troubles in getting POST parameters

login view:

```
def ProcLogin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        account_name = request.POST.get('username','')
        password = ToMd5(request.POST.get('password',''))
        if not account_name or not password: return HttpResponse("invalid input")
```

template code:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'Main:login' %}" class="login_form">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="form-group text-right">
                            <label for="username">User name:</label>
                            <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control box_shadow">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group text-right">
                                <label for="password">Password: </label>
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control box_shadow">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="login_btn"></button>
                        </form>
```

Output when testing it:

[invalid input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6A9a.png)

everything is supposed to be correct except the results aren't. Thank you.

Comment: Your inputs need the "name" attribute to appear in `request.POST`.

Comment: yup @schwobaseggl is right. your input tag should contain name attribute ex: `<input id="username" type="text" name="username">`.

Comment: yes it is indeed fixed now, Thank you both ^^